# Why does the transform-origin CSS property not show up in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am manipulating CSS styles using React with code that resembles this:

```
let el React.findDOMNode(this.refs.thing);
el.style.transform = `translate(${0}px, ${0}px) scale(${1})`;
el.style.transformOrigin = `${100}px ${100}px)`;     // SPOT THE TYPO
```

The transform CSS property works and shows up when I inspect the element in the browser (Chrome). The transform-origin property does not show up, and I cannot figure out why.

I log to the console just before this code, so it is being executed. When I intentionally do something like:

```
el.style['transform-origin'] = etc.
```

I don't get a warning from React, despite using the development build.

Comment: Maybe because of typo? What if you try: `${100}px ${100}px` (last ")" character deleted from your code)

Comment: Ouch! I'll give it a try. Well spotted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As spotted by wintvelt, there was a spurious parenthesis in my code:

```
    el.style.transformOrigin = `${100}px ${100}px`;
```

is correct.